# Python Selenium WebDriver can't execute quit() in new version (2.4.9)

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I just noticed that today after trying to run the same scrape script on a different machine I kept getting an error:

```
File "scrape.py", line 40, in scrape
driver.quit()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 74, in quit
self.service.stop()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 124, in stop
self.process.stdout.close()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
```

The following code originally ran fine on my laptop - Python 2.7.10, Selenium 2.4.8, PhantomJS 2.0.0.

The different machine that originally gave me the error runs Debian 8.2, Python 2.7.9, Selenium 2.4.9, PhantomJS 2.0.0. After comparing, I updated Selenium to 2.4.9 on my laptop and began getting the same error. What changed between Selenium version 2.4.8 and 2.4.9 that quit() does not work for me now, or am I doing something wrong?

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('/Users/sgloutnikov/node_modules/phantomjs2/bin/phantomjs')
driver.get(url)
try:
    onAir = str(driver.find_element_by_id("oapdt").text).splitlines()
except NoSuchElementException:
    logging.error("Error parsing element")
if driver:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tracked down the change that fixes the problem, made 5 hours ago: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/cc07382c786b6b35274957652a7a357d0453279a